# Real-time save in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, real-time

I am creating an app in Qt, similar to scribble (given in sample app).  Purpose is to let user draw freehand and once finished, upload these drawing to net. As of now I am saving the drawing as PNG image every 5 seconds, so that the loss of data in an event of unexpected shut-down is minimum (I kept 5 sec to minimize write operations; Real real-time would be highly desirable).
But the problem is, I am saving the entire page as an image every 5 seconds, where the new data added may be few pixels.  I was wondering if I could write ONLY the new pixels added into the disk; there is no constraint that I should use PNG while saving; I can convert the data to PNG at the end when user says he is finished.

The piece of code for saving very basic;

```
void SaveData(const QString &fileName, const char *fileFormat, QImage image)
{
    mutex.lock();
    QImage visibleImage = image;

    if (visibleImage.save(fileName, fileFormat, 50)) 
    {
    system("sync");
    mutex.unlock();
    return true;

    } else {

    mutex.unlock();
        return false;

    }
}
```

I just wonder if REAL real-time save as the pixels getting added if possible..!

Thanks in advance

DK

Comment: You could use some form of "transaction logging," i.e. just append to a list of events (like `add pixel here`, `add line here` etc.) and when doing an actual PNG-save, "replay" this and save to PNG.

Comment: @Angew, thanks for the suggestion. Have tried something similar; but the core issue remains the same; when to write those 'transaction logs' to disk.  If you do it in every pixel, you land up having so many files, multiple for same pixel for different color, erase, over-write etc.  If you decide to write with a delay say 5 seconds, you are back to square one; you may loose 5 seconds of data. Will try to optimize on this further.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions.
I have 'almost decided' to go ahead with saving all 'dirty blocks', and stitching then together once the user is done.  Although it's not REAL real-time, I have compromised for this as the data volume written to disk is minimum and relevant.  Another reason I was not able to proceed with memory mapped file &c. is, I have copy/paste, redo/undo etc., where saving blocks make life much easier as each block can be roughly mapped to a transaction

Comment: Will get the dirty rectangle from event.pos() on mousepress and mouserelease, and save it. Also will include timer to save in between events, if user is taking too much of time between events.. say doing a shading for few seconds.. etc.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you to use tiles to save the image. Split the canvas to many e.g. 64x64 rectangles. And save each rectangle into separate file. When something is changed, you need to rewrite only few small files instead of rewriting the whole picture.

Also there is another dangerous thing in your code. When you run `QImage::save`, it most likely will erase file contents and write new contents. If the system was shutted down between there two actions, your file will became empty. So it's important to write new contents to a temporary file and then move it to the proper location. Keeping several old version of a file also can be useful. Who knows how the file system will react on the shutdown.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. This will reduce the volume of data written in every 'write'; thus I can write more frequently rather than in every 5 second.
But it would be great if we can 'stream save' the data; mean, changing the pixel values of changed pixels in disk directly; say some low-level write functions.  My array is constant; it is a 1000x1000 drawing area. So I can find out which byte to change; provided I have a method to do so.

..and about image going blank;  I am under the impression that the 'overwriting' stuff is taken care by OS..

Comment: You can use your own `MyImage` class with `setPixel` method. In this method you can change image data on disk and in memory (underlying QImage object). When painting, you can use this QImage object. 'Overwriting stuff' is not taken care by OS, and file can be really lost.

Answer (score 2):

You could maybe use a memory mapped file, something like:

```
    QFile file("rawimage.dat");
    file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
    // Make sure there is enough memory for the image
    quint32 width = 16;
    quint32 height = 16;
    quint32 bpp32 = 4;
    qint64 file_size = width * height * bpp32;
    file.resize(file_size);
    uchar* mem = file.map(0, file_size);

    // make a QImage that uses the file as memory
    QImage img(mem, 16, 16, QImage::Format_ARGB32);
    // Do some drawing in the image
    img.fill(0);

    // finished with the file
    file.unmap(mem);
    file.close();
```

You will need to check that it actually flushes to disk correctly - I haven't tested this.  Ideally on Windows you'd want to be able to call 'FlushViewOfFile' on the memory mapped handle to ensure that modified pages are written to disk.  It doesn't look like there is a way of calling this in Qt so you might need to do something operating system specific here to ensure that the disk image is consistent when you want it to be.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a list of QPainterPath objects of the drawn items, which are then rendered to the QImage. You'd need to change the mouse events to do the following: -

- Mouse Down : create a new QPainterPath (painterPath) and call painterPath->moveTo
- Mouse Move : call painterPath->LineTo
- Mouse Up   : Store the QPainterPath in a list.

In the paint event, you then pass each new QPainterPath to be drawn

To back up, every n seconds, open up a file and append a stream of the new QPainterPaths since the last time the list was saved.

To restore, open the file, stream them back in and draw them on to the Image.

This can be optimised to check for new items and not to bother saving if none exist. In addition, rather than being time based, you could maintain a number of points that are created in the QPainterPath and only save when it exceeds a certain number.

Note that if you do go down this route, you may also want to store Painter settings with each QPainterPath, if the user can also change things such as pen colour, width etc.

Other advantages come with using QPainterpath - for example, the user could open up one image and then a second, choosing to have it drawn on top of the first.

Answer (score 0):

If you want real-time saving then I suggest you use an uncompressed bitmap format. Changing pixels would be as simple as seeking inside the file to the x-y co-ordinates, usually calculated as

```
file.seek(y * lineWidth + x * pixelDataSize);
file.write(pixelData);
```